# How to replace dll files in program files by cmd/bat

Tags: dll, replace, windows-xp, cmd, program-files

I'm trying to do bat file which replaces some dll files under program files\file...

I just can't find solution to do this. I have some win xp and windows 7 computers to run this bat and I'm using xcopy command.

My file copy command is working correctly if destination is something else than under program files.

Does somebody knows the solution for this, please?

Comment: Try running your script as an administrator. Otherwise, post the error.

Comment: A DLL that is currently used cannot be overwritten or deleted. You'd first need to close all open handles to that DLL, although closing them manually wouldn't be a normal thing to do, if ever possible.

Comment: Those dll files are not in use on that time.

Comment: What have you done so far? You should post some code!

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file needs to run [elevated](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/). In older windows versions you can also use the `runas` command to run it as administrator.

Comment: I'm already running bat as admin rights. Command will execute normally and there is no error prompt but it just does not replace old files.

Comment: Then you are maybe trying to replace protected windows files. either by [WPF](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193) or [access rights](http://superuser.com/q/124372/57579).